# Border Radius Nativescript

Tags: css, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Nativescript support this declaration of the property border-radius?

```
border-radius: 10px 80px 80px 10px / 10px 150px 150px 10px;
```

I use this code in a css property on a GridLayout but return an error (too much arguments)

There is another way to get the same effect?

Comment: Apply each one individually for each corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to issue [#77](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/77) NativeScript github, individual border radius for corners is logged, but it's not going to be implemented soon, as they are focused on improving performance and bug fixing.

So, you can only apply the same radius to all corners with styling.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this question, you can now use `border-radius` in nativescript.

Setting `border-radius:0` doesn't remove the border radius as regular Buttons in Android all have it - but if you also add `border-width: 1` you get straight edges.

```
Button {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-width: 1;
}
```